# WinDbg configuration for debugging a dll

Tags: c#, c++, memory-leaks, windbg

I am trying to use WinDbg to detect memory leak in a unmanaged dll.

Suppose I have a MyDll.dll (**unmanaged**) needs debug, and I have a MyExe.exe (**managed**). that calls MyDll.dll. Here is what I did, which did not work:

- Adding **SRV*f:\localsymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols** to WinDbg
- Adding **C:\MyPath\MyExe\Bin\Debug\MyDll.dll** to WinDbg
- Run MyExe.exe, and attach WinDbg to MyExe.exe

So basically the MyDll.dll will be copied into C:\MyPath\MyExe\Bin\Debug\MyDll.dll. As MyExe.exe runs, MyDll.dll will be called.

But I don't my configuration working, because I don't see any dynamic updates in the WinDbg window when the program is running, where leak is supposed to happening.

I am wondering how exactly I should configure WinDbg to detect this memory leak in MyDll.dll? I am on **Win7, VS2008 and .NET3.5**

Thanks.

Comment: No one had similar experience before?

Comment: Look at "Using UMDH to Find a User-Mode Memory Leak" in the windbg help.

Comment: So the symbol file for UMDH should be MyDll.pdb, which is the pdb file for the suspicious dll, or the symbol file of the MyExe.exe?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. What exactly are you expecting to see in WinDbg window?

Comment: I am trying to see where the memory leak is in the WinDbg. I am starting to use this tool, and have not used to it yet.

Comment: WinDBG will just tells you where you have memory leaks. its a debugger , not a memory leak detection tool.(it can help , but thats not is main purpose)